# When I get the Force Close dialog, I have a Report button. Where did it come from?

Tags: android

I feel a little bit silly asking this, but I haven't been able to find any answers on my own.  My Force Close dialog has a "Report" button. I think it's a great idea, and I wish everyone had it. At first, I thought it must be something I turned on without realizing it, but not only can't I find any setting that I might have touched, I also can't find any reference to this button existing on the Internet. I have a Droid, and I know 4 other people with Droids, and they say they don't have the option to report Force Closes. Am I special? Am I just missing something?  The "report" button has been there for at least a few weeks now.

When I use the Report button, I get a screen with a "feedback" field and a checkbox for "Include system data". Below that , it says "Information from feedback reports will be shown to the developer of the application."  Under that are Preview and Send buttons.

As a developer, I've never received one of these reports.

I'd try to send a report to myself, but it seemingly only shows the button for apps installed from the market, and I don't know of a way to crash my production app.

I suppose I could publish a simple crashing app just to try it out, but I thought I'd ask you folks first.

Edit:
You can view screenshots here: http://bentobin.com/crashReportImages/

Comment: Intriguing .. it would be blinking marvelous if this was a standard feature and developers could view exception reports in the Market panel. Instead we have to jerry-rig our own. 

Two questions, is this all apps, and are you using consumer Android builds, not some fancy custom build?

Comment: I've never seen this. Do you have a screenshot you can post?

Comment: I am using the standard build for a Droid. This appeared for me in version 2.0.1, and is still present after my recent upgrade to 2.1. I don't think it appeared when I upgraded from 2.0 to 2.0.1, though. I think it appeared at some point after. I'll add screenshot links to the main question in a moment.

Comment: Oh, and yes, this appears in all apps as long as they come from the Market. I do not get the Report button if I crash a non-Market app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new feature of Android :)

Comment: Interesting, especially if reports really are available for developers. In which version was this introduced, or how?

Comment: Please tell me that if we implement a default `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` that we will override this behavior. Otherwise, since developers have no control over what is in the report, some applications may violate laws (e.g., HIPAA).

Comment: So, is it being ramped up slowly or something? It doesn't appear to be perfected yet, as my screenshot shows a date of Dec 31, 1969 being sent.

Comment: It's a bit sad that his happened, again, without involving the community.
For the features, I have yet to see it, but the initiative is great and was long needed.
Hopefully this data will also be seen by Google, not only the developers. That way the engineers would get feedback on what is broken or not well understood on the platform.

Comment: Last not least, I can't see from the screenshots how to contact the submitter, but this is definitively a very important feature and with the Market we have enough one way communications. Optionally submitting anonymously would be ok for me though.

Comment: Can we configure this thing? For example, changing the email address where to send this 'Report' ?