# How to show a custom force close dialog?

Tags: android

During some testing the other day on a Galaxy Tab 10.1, the Facebook app force closed. The "force close" dialog looked different, however; there were two buttons, "force close" and "report." If I clicked "report" I had the option to type in extra text, preview and send the report. This seems like a valuable tool for any app to gather diagnostic information from users; but how can I implement that in my apps? I'd love to see a tutorial or full working example.

Comment: the report button is [standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567197/when-i-get-the-force-close-dialog-i-have-a-report-button-where-did-it-come-fro) and you might be able to get the report via market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the default error report dialog. You won't ever see it while debugging. It will only show to end users who have downloaded your app from Google Play.

Comment: Thanks David--that explains why I hadn't seen it before. I feel dumb now! Here I was thinking that must have been custom functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Do check out [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) doesn't take very long to set up and does the job reporting uncaught exceptions and errors.

Comment: I do use ACRA. My question was about implementing a custom dialog to handle force closes, and I am not aware of a way to use ACRA to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've seen links such as [How to give event on force close dialog's ok button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826704/how-to-give-event-on-force-close-dialogs-ok-button) and [Ideal way to set global uncaught exception Handler in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android) that mention UncaughtExceptionHandler, and one poster even mentioned Acra, but I have yet to see a WORKING example.